# where do you prefer to put Login and Logout functionality when using MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

This is my first question. please bear with me :)

Where do you usually put your Login and Logout functionality when using Model-View-Controller pattern? is it in Model? View? or Controller?

Answer (score 0):

The GUI part of the login/logout (so the screen) in the View.
The functionality of logging in/out in the Model.
And the interaction between the View and the Model in the Controller.

But I think this is general for all items regarding MVC.

Comment: Why would controller have any [impact](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/MVC-Process.png) on interaction between views and model? View acquires data directly from model layer. Not intermediary required.

Comment: Because the user possibly might need to input log in name/credentials via the Controller.

Comment: That made NO sense. Just the fact, that  controller passes some values to model layer, has no impact on how information from model layer ends up in view.